# Pandas NaN introduced by pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pivot-table, nan

I have a table containing some countries and their KPI from the world-banks API. this looks like [image: no nan values present]. As you can see no nan values are present.

However, I need to pivot this table to bring int into the right shape for analysis. A `pd.pivot_table(countryKPI, index=['germanCName'], columns=['indicator.id'])`
For some e.g. `TUERKEI` this works just fine:

[image: for turkey it works]
But for most of the countries strange nan values are introduced. How can I prevent this?

[image: strange nan values]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think the best way to understand `pivoting` is to apply it to a small sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

countryKPI = pd.DataFrame({'germanCName':['a','a','b','c','c'],
                           'indicator.id':['z','x','z','y','m'],
                           'value':[7,8,9,7,8]})

print (countryKPI)
  germanCName indicator.id  value
0           a            z      7
1           a            x      8
2           b            z      9
3           c            y      7
4           c            m      8

print (pd.pivot_table(countryKPI, index=['germanCName'], columns=['indicator.id']))
             value               
indicator.id     m    x    y    z
germanCName                      
a              NaN  8.0  NaN  7.0
b              NaN  NaN  NaN  9.0
c              8.0  NaN  7.0  NaN
```

If need replace `NaN` to `0` add parameter `fill_value`:

```
print (countryKPI.pivot_table(index='germanCName', 
                              columns='indicator.id', 
                              values='value', 
                              fill_value=0))
indicator.id  m  x  y  z
germanCName             
a             0  8  0  7
b             0  0  0  9
c             8  0  7  0
```

Comment: Indeed this example is good. But how can I prevent the NaN values?

Comment: Ok, what do you need? `NaN` replace to `0`?

Comment: I see so the problem is that in my data for some countries not all indicators were reported ... :(

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is problem why you get NaN.

Comment: But a call to http://api.worldbank.org/countries/eg/indicators/NY.GDP.MKTP.CD?format=json&MRV=1&gapfill=Y&per_page=100 indeed returns some data -> which strangely did not result in my download pd.Dataframe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123918/discussion-between-georg-heiler-and-jezrael).

Comment: any idea why when I add fill_values=0, it doesn't do anything? I want it to count the 0's (missing values in my average) in the pivot table but it doesn't take the missing values into account.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
piv_out = pd.pivot_table(countryKPI, index=['germanCName'], columns=['indicator.id'])

print(piv_out.to_string(na_rep=""))
```

Answer (score -2):

As per documentations:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html

**pivot method returns:**  reshaped DataFrame.

Now you can replace the na values with any desired values, using fillna method.

**FOR EXAMPLE:**

MY PIVOT RETURNS THE BELOW dataFrame:

[image: PIVOT RETURN DATA TYPE]
**Now I want to replace the Nan with 0, I will  apply the fillna() method on the returned data frame from pivot method**

[image: DATA FRAME RETURN AFTER REPLACING Nan values with 0]